MDT removing old VB programs after sysprep
Good morning.  I have installed 2 old vb programs on an image build in MDT however when I sysprep and capture the image and apply it to a laptop those programs are gone from the image.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

sysprep is a bit complicated(simple, but complicated). Why you cant use MDT for that purpose and deploy them with MDT? Ever tough about slip-streaming those(tho i still fail to see, why cant you deploy it with MDT?)? Can you provide a bit more details about VB and how you added it to MDT? Do you use WDS or you are making bootable usb with it? If you do use MDT with WDS, then you are only short on info about $OEM$ folder i assume.
